# HC-05 module short circuit

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

I have bought a HC05 bluetooth module and I think I accidentally short circuited it. Is there any way to change the voltage regulator or methods to reuse it again?

Comment: Accept the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're referring to the HC05 module, already soldered on a board, with the 6-pin header. The regulator is on that board.

Online you'll find several versions of that board, therefore you should check the schematics, to find which you need to mount. For instance, on some board, a R1114-33 is used.

Changing the regulator is not the hardest task on earth, however, other components are very close to it (capacitors).

Still there are 2 things to consider:

- Is it worthy to change the regulator? That module will cost few
  bucks.
- As you can see from the datasheet, the regulator is short-circuit protected (yes, it does not mean that it will be indestructible). I think, instead, you destroyed one of the two ICs of the bluetooth module soldered on board. And those one, beside of being quite difficult to find and expensive in small quantity, they are very hard do replace.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment sir. I have already lost 2 of them due t short circuit issue ,which is really frustrating .So instead of buying I wanted to fix it. Is there any way to know if the Bluetooth ICs are destroyed?

Comment: @curious-boy do they heat up? If yes, they are dead. If not, this does not mean that they aren't... How and where did you short circuit the module? I.e. which pin?

Comment: yes they heat up .I guess i have to buy a new one.

Comment: I think that this has been caused by:
1) accidentally a wire (powered at 5V) contacted one of the various solder joints of your board. (always turn off power when mounting the circuit!) 2) maybe you should consider to put a resistor in series to the TXD and RXD lines (yes, many modules already have them, but in some of them they are just 100 Ohm! too low for a 5V to 3.3V conversion! Put 10k  if you're going up to 115200). 

To be sure: you didn't connect that module to a serial port of a PC, right? The serial port outputs up to 12V on the RXD and TXD lines...